# create csv file on cloud storage with only 10 records

Tags: java, google-app-engine, google-cloud-storage, google-cloud-platform

```
GcsService gcsService = GcsServiceFactory.createGcsService();
        String fileName=fileNameWithOutExtension+".csv";
        GcsFilename gcsFileName = new GcsFilename(bucketName ,fileName);
        GcsFileOptions gcsFileOptions = new GcsFileOptions.Builder().mimeType("text/csv").acl(aclType).build();
        GcsOutputChannel gcsoutputChannel = gcsService.createOrReplace(gcsFileName, gcsFileOptions);
        gcsoutputChannel.write(ByteBuffer.wrap(header.getBytes()));
        for(T object : list){
            gcsoutputChannel.write(ByteBuffer.wrap(object.toString().replace("null", "").getBytes("UTF-8")));
        }
        gcsoutputChannel.close();
        if(StringUtility.isNotNullOrBlank(emailId)){
            String downloadUrl = "https://storage.googleapis.com/"+bucketName+"/"+fileName;
            EmailUtil.sendJobReportCompletionMail(emailId, downloadUrl);
        }


this is my code to create CSV file on cloud storage.
```

but i want to write only 10 records in one file and next 10 records should go to new automatically generated file filename 2.csv.

i have tried this

```
GcsService gcsService = GcsServiceFactory.createGcsService();
        String fileName=fileNameWithOutExtension+".csv";
        int i=1,counter = 0;
        GcsFilename gcsFileName = new GcsFilename(bucketName ,fileName);
        GcsFileOptions gcsFileOptions = new GcsFileOptions.Builder().mimeType("text/csv").acl(aclType).build();
        GcsOutputChannel gcsoutputChannel = gcsService.createOrReplace(gcsFileName, gcsFileOptions);
        gcsoutputChannel.write(ByteBuffer.wrap(header.getBytes()));
        for(T object : list){

            if(counter == 10)
            {
                fileName=fileNameWithOutExtension+i+".csv";
                gcsFileName = new GcsFilename(bucketName ,fileName);
                gcsFileOptions = new GcsFileOptions.Builder().mimeType("text/csv").acl(aclType).build();
                gcsoutputChannel = gcsService.createOrReplace(gcsFileName, gcsFileOptions);


            }else
            {
            gcsoutputChannel.write(ByteBuffer.wrap(object.toString().replace("null", "").getBytes("UTF-8")));
            }

        }
        gcsoutputChannel.close();
        if(StringUtility.isNotNullOrBlank(emailId)){
            String downloadUrl = "https://storage.googleapis.com/"+bucketName+"/"+fileName;
            EmailUtil.sendJobReportCompletionMail(emailId, downloadUrl);
        }
    }catch(IOException e){
        logger.log(Level.SEVERE,"Error wrinting to GCS:",e);
    }
    logger.log(Level.INFO, list.toString());
    logger.log(Level.INFO,"Wrinting to GCS completed");
}
```

but i am confuse now.
i can create new file but how can i write on that file using same for loop?

Comment: I think your code has a few bugs.  First, it never modifies "i" or "counter".  Second, counter == 10 would only output exactly the 10th (or 11th, depending on when you increment) record to filename2.csv

Answer (score 0):

Rather buggy and incomplete code. Try this, instead, for your main loop:

```
for(T object : list){
    gcsoutputChannel.write(ByteBuffer.wrap(object.toString().replace("null", "").getBytes("UTF-8")));
    counter += 1;
    if(counter == 10)
    {
        gcsoutputChannel.close();
        fileName=fileNameWithOutExtension+i+".csv";
        i += 1;
        gcsFileName = new GcsFilename(bucketName ,fileName);
        gcsFileOptions = new GcsFileOptions.Builder().mimeType("text/csv").acl(aclType).build();
        gcsoutputChannel = gcsService.createOrReplace(gcsFileName, gcsFileOptions);
    }
}
if(counter > 0)
{
    gcsoutputChannel.close();
}
```